# How to use Reusable database modules in SAP HANA XSA?

Tags: hana

I am trying to build re-usable db component in HANA XSA which can be used in another application's data persistence model. For this scenario, I tried to follow sap help provided at [this link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4505d0bdaf4948449b7f7379d24d0f0d/2.0.04/en-US/ceef254dec8d48489f49a7095ebb999d.html) but unfortunately I was not able to achieve results. I was able to successfully create a reusable component but when I use it in another application I get error while building the consuming app.

```
Your module contains a package.json file, it will be used for the build.

2:55:33 PM (DIBuild) npm ERR! code E404npm ERR! 404 Not Found: dependent-module-name-db@0.0.1
```

The above error tells me that the builder is not able to resolve the dependency. For some reason it doesn't know where to find the dependent module. I was wondering if I could register this component in some sort of registry and then the build-pack finds it but don't know how. can someone help on this?

P.S. : I was wondering ( a silly thought :D ) if I could deploy the reusable module which then gets registered in some sort of internal registry in XSA but then I gave up the idea because there is no deploy script in package.json for reusable module.

I highly appreciate any help in this regards. This thing has been holding me since yesterday.

Cheers,

~ A curious developer

Comment: The documentation explains that the module's `<module_name>/src` and `<module_name>/cfg` folders have to be findable in the `node_modules` folder. Have you placed those folders there?

Comment: Hi @LarsBr. Thanks for responding. I was hoping that if I mention the module as a dependency in package.json of db module in consuming module, it will download the dependencies in node_folder but for that I need to make my reusable component available as a package in some node package repository which is not mentioned in the documentation but I am assuming it to work like that. Is this a wrong assumption? Also if I have place them manually how come I make the reusable component to be maintained independently and any changes available globally? Btw, As we talk I am trying aforesaid approach.

Answer (score 0):

To use reuse db component, we have to create synonym and create a hana db connection from the application. You also have to create grants file to provide the roles.